# Difference between new View.OnClickListener and new OnClickListener

Tags: android

I become curious about the difference between these two classes.
My code is..

```
    main_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d(MAINBOTTOM_FRAGMENT_TAG,"main button clicked!");
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fblogin_Fragment = new FbLoginFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, fblogin_Fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();    
        }
    });

    setting_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d(MAINBOTTOM_FRAGMENT_TAG,"setting button clicked!");
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(
            setting_Fragment = new SettingFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container,setting_Fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();   
        }
    });
```

The project runs fine, nothing extraordinary. However, I'm a little bit confused which one to use it.
OnClickListener or View.OnClickListener?
thanks.

Comment: Probably the way you auto-generated it?

Comment: im more curious  how your buttons onclick are not @Overriding....

Comment: It is exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're imported `View.OnClickListener`, both will refer to the same class and will work identically.

`View.OnClickListener` is just often used to distinguish from `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.